# Excluding a string in a regex matching, for sed processing

Tags: regex, sed

I need to match this for a substitute command:

```
whatever__MATCH_THIS__whateverwhatever__AND_THIS__whateverwhatever
```

I am trying with:

```
sed -e 's/__\(.*\)__/\{{\1}}/g' myfile
```

But this is eagerly matching `__MATCH_THIS__whateverwhatever__AND_THIS__`, producing:

```
whatever{{MATCH_THIS__whateverwhatever__AND_THIS}}whateverwhatever
```

But I wanted:

```
whatever{{MATCH_THIS}}whateverwhatever{{AND_THIS}}whateverwhatever
```

How can I specify a string to exclude, in the matching part? I know how to exclude *one* character (for example `[^a]`) but not how to exclude a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a non-greedy regex, but unfortunately sed doesn't allow that. However, it can be done in perl.

```
perl -pe 's|__(.*?)__|{{$1}}|g' <myfile
```

The question mark after the asterisk denotes the matcher as being non-greedy, so instead of taking the longest matching string it can find, it'll take the shortest.

Hope that helps.

If you wanted to put this in a perl script rather than run on the command line, then something like this will do the job:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; # Habit of mine
use 5.0100; # So we can use 'say'

# Save the matching expression in a variable. 
# qr// tells us it's a regex-like quote (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qr.html)
my $regex = qr/__(.*?)__/;

# Ordinarily, I'd write this in a way I consider to be less perl-y and more readable.
# What it's doing is reading from the filename supplied on STDIN and places the
# contents of the file in $_. Then it runs the substitution on the string, before
# printing out the result.
while (<>) {
  $_ =~ s/$regex/{{$1}}/g;
  say $_;
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
./regex myfile
whatever{{MATCH_THIS}}whateverwhatever{{AND_THIS}}whateverwhatever
```

It's Perl, there are a million and one ways to do it!

Comment: Are all sed scripts compatible with perl? That is, if I have a working sed script, can I feed it to `perl -pe` and hope it will just work? The reason why I ask is that I usually do my refactorings with sed, and knowing of this sed limitation, I will move to perl, but I do not want surprises in the future.

Comment: Probably not directly, no. There is a script called s2p which allegedly converts between the two, but I've never got it to do anything other than produce errors! I use sed for a lot of perl refactoring, oddly enough!

Comment: Thanks. By the way, how can I have the script in a file using perl? What is the flag to tell perl: the regex is in file `my.regex`?

Answer (score 3):

One way using `sed` although is clear that is not the best tool to do the job. I've commented the code to see what happens because it seems a little confused:

```
sed -n '
    ## Insert a newline just before each "__". This is the most
    ## important instruction of all the script. The game is that
    ## newline character is the only want that sed cannot find in
    ## a line of data, so use it to know where there will be "__"
    ## to change. For each part changed the script will save it
    ## in hold space, but due to constraints of those (only two
    ## spaces) I will have to play deleting and recovering data
    ## several times between both.
    s/__/\n&/g

    ## Save in hold space all data until first newline.
    ## So it means, just before the first "__" of the line.
    h ; s/\n.*$// ; x

    ## Remove that part just saved in hold space.
    s/^[^\n]*\n//

    ## Set a label to jump it later.
    :a

    ## This is end condition. When not found any newline
    ## in the pattern space means that there are no more "__" to 
    ## process, so get all data saved in hold space, print
    ## it and leave hold space empty ready for next line of 
    ## the input file.
    /^[^\n]\+$/ {
        g
        p
        x
        s/^.*$//
        x
        b
    }

    ## This part of code will process next two input lines.
    ## First one has the first pair of "__" and second one has
    ## the end pair, so substitute to each respective curly
    ## braces.
    s/__/{{/

    ## Once the substitution has been done, save it adding to
    ## hold space.
    ## I add all the line but only want to keep until first newline.
    ## I delete two of them because "H" command adds it one by itself.
    H ; x ; s/\n// ; s/\n.*$// ; x

    ## Delete part just processed and saved in hold space.
    s/^[^\n]*\n//

    ## Repeat same process for end pair of "__"
    s/__/}}/
    H ; x ; s/\n// ; s/\n.*$// ; x
    s/^[^\n]*\n//

    ## Goto label "a"
    ba 
' infile
```

Paste and run it from command line, with your two lines provided it yields:

```
whatever{{MATCH_THIS}}whateverwhatever{{AND_THIS}}whateverwhatever
exten => s,n,ExecIf($[${amacode} == 1]?Set(rateparams_view={{INCOMING_RATEPARAMS_VIEW}}):Set(rateparams_view={{OUTGOING_RATEPARAMS_VIEW}}))
```

Answer (score 3):

### GNU sed

```
sed ':k s/__/{{/;s/__/}}/;tk' file
```

input:

```
whatever__MATCH_THIS__whateverwhatever__AND_THIS__whateverwhatever
blah__XXX_XX__blah_blah_blah__XX_XXX__whateverwhatever
```

output:

```
whatever{{MATCH_THIS}}whateverwhatever{{AND_THIS}}whateverwhatever
blah{{XXX_XX}}blah_blah_blah{{XX_XXX}}whateverwhatever
```

Comment: wonderful. Can you detail it a bit more for non sed gurus ?

Answer (score 1):

`sed` does not support PCRE goodies such as the non-greedy operator

I was able to get around your situation with the following variation:

```
echo 'whatever__MATCH_THIS__whateverwhatever__AND_THIS__whateverwhatever' |
sed -e 's/__\([^_]\+_[^_]\+\)__/\{{\1}}/g'
whatever{{MATCH_THIS}}whateverwhatever{{AND_THIS}}whateverwhatever
```

Comment: It looked promising but take a look at this input data: `exten => s,n,ExecIf($[${amacode} == 1]?Set(rateparams_view=__INCOMING_RATEPARAMS_VIEW__):Set(rateparams_view=__OUTGOING_RATEPARAMS_VIEW__))`

Comment: @gonvaled, ah you just moved the goalposts on me there :-). I am not sure it is within `sed`'s capabilities to handle your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/__([^_]+(_[^_]+)*)__/{{\1}}/g' file
```

or, perhaps easier to understand:

```
sed -r 's/__/\n/g;s/\n([^\n]*)\n/{{\1}}/g;s/\n/__/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on my windows XP laptop

```
input command
echo whatever__MATCH_THIS__whateverwhatever__AND_THIS__whateverwhatever|sed -f a.sed
output
whatever{{__MATCH_THIS__}}whateverwhatever{{__AND_THIS__}}whateverwhatever
where a.sed is this

    /__MATCH_THIS__/{
    /__AND_THIS__/{
    s/__MATCH_THIS__/\{\{__MATCH_THIS__\}\}/
    s/__AND_THIS__/\{\{__AND_THIS__\}\}/
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong but I guess it is as simple as that:

```
sed -r 's/__(.*)__(.*)__(.*)__/\{{\1}}\2{{\3}}/g'
```

Test it as follows: (works for me)

```
echo "whatever__MATCH_THIS__whateverwhatever__AND_THIS__whateverwhatever"|sed -r 's/__(.*)__(.*)__(.*)__/\{{\1}}\2{{\3}}/g'
```

results in:

```
whatever{{MATCH_THIS}}whateverwhatever{{AND_THIS}}whateverwhatever
```