# Extracting a portion of a string then using it to match with other strings in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I previously asked for assistance [parsing a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448767/splitting-rearranging-excluding-strings-from-a-text-file-in-powershell-to-outp/42451412#42451412) and have been using this code for my script:

```
import-csv $File -header Tag,Date,Value|
  Where {$_.Tag -notmatch '(_His_|_Manual$)'}|
    Select-Object *,@{Name='Building';Expression={"{0} {1}" -f $($_.Tag -split '_')[1..2]}}|
      Format-table -Groupby Building -Property Tag,Date,Value
```

I've realized since then that, while the code filters out any tags containing `_His` or `_Manual`, I need to also filter any tags associated with `_Manual`. For example, the following tags are present in my text file:

```
L01_B111_BuildingName1_MainElectric_111A01ME_ALC,13-Apr-17 08:45,64075
L01_B111_BuildingName1_MainElectric_111A01ME_Cleansed,13-Apr-17 08:45,64075
L01_B111_BuildingName1_MainElectric_111A01ME_Consumption,13-Apr-17 08:45,10.4
L01_B333_BuildingName3_MainWater_333E02MW_Manual,1-Dec-16 18:00:00,4.380384E+07
L01_B333_BuildingName3_MainWater_333E02MW_Cleansed,1-Dec-16 18:00:00,4.380384E+07 
L01_B333_BuildingName3_MainWater_333E02MW_Consumption,1-Dec-16 18:00:00,25.36
```

The `333E02MW_Manual` string would be excluded using my current code, but how could I also exclude `333E02MW_Cleansed` and `333E02MW_Consumption`? I feel I would need something that will allow me to extract the 8-digit code before each `_Manual` instance and then use it to find any other strings with a `{MatchingCode}`

```
xxx_xxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx_MatchingCode_Cleansed
xxx_xxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx_MatchingCode_Consumption
```

I know there are the `-like` `-contains` and `-match` operators and I've seen these posts on using [substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603128/check-if-string-contains-any-substring-in-an-array-powershell) and [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132936/how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-one-of-multiple-substrings), but how could I extract the MatchingCode to actually have something to match to? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874586/excluding-a-string-in-a-regex-matching-for-sed-processing) seems to come closest to my goal, but I'm not sure how to apply it to PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find every tag that ends with `_Manual` and create a regex pattern that matches any of the parts before `_Manual`. Ex.

```
$Data = Import-Csv -Path $File -Header Tag,Date,Value
#Create regex that matches any prefixes that has a manual row (matches using the value before _Manual)
$ExcludeManualPattern = ($Data | Foreach-Object { if($_.Tag -match '^(.*?)_Manual$') { [regex]::Escape($Matches[1]) } }) -join '|'

$Data | Where-Object { $_.Tag -notmatch '_His_' -and $_.Tag -notmatch $ExcludeManualPattern } |
Select-Object -Property *,@{Name='Building';Expression={"{0} {1}" -f $($_.Tag -split '_')[1..2]}}|
Format-table -GroupBy Building -Property Tag,Date,Value
```

Comment: Nice extension of my initial script, +1